# How do I send link to sharepoint file as an attachment via power automate?

Tags: power-automate

I have a file on sharepoint and I would like to send an email with this file where the attachment would open the sharepoint. At this moment the attachment opens a hardcopy of a file. How do I attach a link to a sharepoint file in power automate so that it appears as an attachment not as a link in the body of the email?
[image]

In other word, how do I replicate "share link" option? Because my flow at the moment attaches a file which will open in desktop app (and thus any changes to it will not be saved on sharepoint?).

[image]

Comment: Sorry but that’s an oxymoron. You’re either attaching a file or providing a link to the file, which is it that you want to do? “Where the attachment would open the SharePoint”?!?

Comment: Maybe the poster means open in Excel Online versus opening in the Excel Desktop application? That is a default open behaviour setting in document libraries, https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-default-office-files-to-open-in-the-native-app-from-sharepoint-and-onedrive/

Comment: Please see update of the original question. I would like to find a way to do "share link" via power automate flow. How can I do it?